# Float Div keep its Width when there is no content

Tags: html, css, width

I have 3 `<p>` with set widths, but occassionally i there will be no content inside of them, but I need them to keep their widths, even if no content is inside the `<p>`.

```
<div class="grid_12 alpha omega directory-phone-table-row">
        <p class="grid_3 phone-name omega"><a href="javascript:;">${firstname}, ${lastname}</a></p>
        <p class="grid_3 alpha omega">${phonework}</p>
        <p class="grid_3 alpha omega">${departmentName}</p>
    </div>

.directory-phone-table .directory-phone-table-data p{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question or try rewording it.

Comment: Have you tried setting `display` attribute to `inline-block` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to define a width of a block element when there is no content inside. At least, from my experience anyway. What I normally do is put spaces where you might expect an empty value (better yet, use the html code for space: `&nbsp;`). If you have a way to return a space character if data returns nothing -- go that route, otherwise you can put a space at the end of your variables like so:

```
<p class="grid_3 phone-name omega"><a href="javascript:;">${firstname}, ${lastname}&nbsp;</a></p>
<p class="grid_3 alpha omega">${phonework}&nbsp;</p>
<p class="grid_3 alpha omega">${departmentName}&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3), user-agents should ignore empty p-elements. Therefor it shouldn't be possible to style an empty p-element. From the spec:

> We discourage authors from using empty P elements. User agents should
>   ignore empty P elements.

In your case, you could use a `div` or `span` element instead of the `p`, which will allow you to style it even if it is empty.

If you for some reason still want to use the `p`-element you could "trick" the browser by adding `&nbsp;` as the content, but that seems like a somewhat ugly solution. I would prefer switching to a more appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

With your current example, your CSS selector is not targeting the

tags within the HTML that you provided. You specified `.directory-phone-table .directory-phone-table-data` in your CSS but the

are in `directory-phone-table-row`

If you just use `.directory-phone-table-row p` you should be good to go

Comment: You can also use min-width in you want the <p> tags to be a little more flexible, but I am not sure how compatible this will be across browsers (in other words older IEs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` instead of empty

Answer (score 0):

You can add a border with the same color as the background although that is really really ugly. Instead of floats you could also use display:inline-block, like so:

```
.directory-phone-table .directory-phone-table-data p{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;  
}​
```

This won't work in IE6 though